# Checking multiple array elements and return true if all matched

Tags: scala

I wanted to find if all emement of below array matched to each other:

```
val a = Array(1,1,1)
val b = Array(1,0,1)
val c = Array(0,1,1)
```

here output should be

```
Array(0,0,1)
```

as all the value of a(2),b(2) and c(2) is 1 however for all cases it's 0. Is there any functional way of solving this in Scala?

Comment: There are several ways to solve this problem, but we are not here to just write the code for you. Please include the code of your attempts to make it work, and we can help you if/when you face problems.

Comment: Will always all arrays will have the same size? Will always be only three arrays?

Comment: Yes size is same and total 3 array we have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the arrays are all the same size, then one approach is to [`transpose`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/Array.html#transpose[U](implicitasArray:T=%3EArray[U]):Array[Array[U]]) the arrays, then map-and-[`reduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/Array.html#reduce[A1%3E:A](op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1) the result with Java's bitwise AND operator `&`:

```
val a = Array(1, 1, 1)
val b = Array(1, 0, 1)
val c = Array(0, 1, 1)

val result = Array(a, b, c).transpose.map(_.reduce(_ & _)) // Array(0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey Chung for the code.Its helped me.However to improve functional programming do you have any resources or books to start with.